# Keypairs limit for an EOS Account

Tags: keys, public-key

How many keypairs can I link to a sigle EOS Account? What if i need 10000 keypairs for the same account?

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many key pairs as you want. This is the unique conept in EOS by using which you can maintain the permissions for your different actions defined in contract. 
You can assign different key pairs to different actions by setting special permissons. Use `set permission` command to assign a particular key pair to execute a specific action in your contract.